# Cannot destructure property 'value' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am getting an error
`Cannot destructure property 'value' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined`.
and I am not sure what went wrong. I have some code here that sets the context and using the context. Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciated.

**userContext.js**

```
import {createContext} from 'react'

export const UserContext = createContext()
```

**App.js**

```
import {UserContext} from './component/userContext'
import {useState} from 'react'

function App() {
   const [value, setValue] = useState("Guest")
  return (
    <div> 
      <Router>
         <UserContext.Provider value={{value, setValue}}>
            <BootstrapNavbar/>  
         </UserContext.Provider> 
      </Router>
     </div>
```

**Signin.js**

```
import React, {useState,useContext} from 'react'
import {UserContext} from './userContext'

const Signin = () => {
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)
    const {value, setValue} = useContext(UserContext)
}
```

**Error**

```
    TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'value' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined.

    const {value, setValue} = useContext(UserContext)
```

Comment: Signin.js is inside BootstrapNavbar?

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to provide **wrap** your **App.js**
And you can take a look at this [blog post](https://ankurraina.medium.com/reactjs-pass-functions-through-context-typeerror-cannot-destructure-property-of-450a8edd55b6)

Answer (score 0):

Export `UserContext` this way

```
const UserContext = React.createContext(); // Create a context object

export {
  UserContext // Export it so it can be used by other Components
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const value = useContext(UserContext)
```